# Python Mechanize Prevent Connection:Close

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to use mechanize to get information from a web page. It's basically succeeding in getting the first bit of information, but the web page includes a button for "Next" to get more information. I can't figure out how to programmatically get the additional information.

By using Live HTTP Headers, I can see the http request that is generated when I click the next button within a browser. It seems as if I can issue the same request using mechanize, but in the latter case, instead of getting the next page, I am redirected to the home page of the website.

Obviously, mechanize is doing something different than my browser is, but I can't figure out what. In comparing the headers, I did find one difference, which was the browser used

Connection: keep-alive

while mechanize used

Connection: close

I don't know if that's the culprit, but when I tried to add the header ('Connection','keep-alive'), it didn't change anything.

[UPDATE]
When I click the button for "page 2" within Firefox, the generated http is (according to Live HTTP Headers):

```
GET /statistics/movies/ww_load/the-fast-and-the-furious-6-2012?authenticity_token=ItU38334Qxh%2FRUW%2BhKoWk2qsPLwYKDfiNRoSuifo4ns%3D&facebook_fans_page=2&tbl=facebook_fans&authenticity_token=ItU38334Qxh%2FRUW%2BhKoWk2qsPLwYKDfiNRoSuifo4ns%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: www.boxoffice.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Prototype-Version: 1.6.0.3
Referer: http://www.boxoffice.com/statistics/movies/the-fast-and-the-furious-6-2012
Cookie: __utma=179025207.1680379428.1359475480.1360001752.1360005948.13; __utmz=179025207.1359475480.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __qca=P0-668235205-1359475480409; zip=13421; country_code=US; _boxoffice_session=2202c6a47fc5eb92cd0ba57ef6fbd2c8; __utmc=179025207; user_credentials=d3adbc6ecf16c038fcbff11779ad16f528db8ebd470befeba69c38b8a107c38e9003c7977e32c28bfe3955909ddbf4034b9cc396dac4615a719eb47f49cc9eac%3A%3A15212; __utmb=179025207.2.10.1360005948
Connection: keep-alive
```

When I try to request the same url within mechanize, it looks like this:

```
GET /statistics/movies/ww_load/the-fast-and-the-furious-6-2012?facebook_fans_page=2&tbl=facebook_fans&authenticity_token=ZYcZzBHD3JPlupj%2F%2FYf4dQ42Kx9ZBW1gDCBuJ0xX8X4%3D HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: www.boxoffice.com
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: close
Cookie: _boxoffice_session=ced53a0ca10caa9757fd56cd89f9983e; country_code=US; zip=13421; user_credentials=d3adbc6ecf16c038fcbff11779ad16f528db8ebd470befeba69c38b8a107c38e9003c7977e32c28bfe3955909ddbf4034b9cc396dac4615a719eb47f49cc9eac%3A%3A15212
Referer: http://www.boxoffice.com/statistics/movies/the-fast-and-the-furious-6-2012
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1
```

--
Daryl

Comment: It would be very strange if that were the issue. The `Connection` header just indicates whether the server should keep the connection open to send another web page. Here the browser is requesting the connection be kept open so it can download images etc., but mechanize doesn't need that so it can tell the server it's done, and will request a new connection next time it wants to load a page. If you could post a more complete accounting of the two requests, it might help.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to include more information. Part of the problem is that the "next" button isn't just a url, it's a javascript call, but ultimately the javascript causes an http request, so it seems that I should be able to issue that request directly within mechanize.

Comment: Not posting an answer because I'm just guessing, but the server might be checking `X-Requested-With` and/or `X-Prototype-Version`. See if you can duplicate those in mechanize.

Answer (score 1):

The server was checking `X-Requested-With` and/or `X-Prototype-Version`, so adding those two headers to the mechanize request fixed it.

Comment: Hey Daryl - you should post the actual content of the answer here, because that comment could disappear at any moment. No need to offer thanks in the answer.

Comment: In fact, I edited the answer to give you an example of how we prefer answers to be written around here. You don't have to use my edit; feel free to change it again yourself, if you want to write it differently.

Comment: @Daryl McCullough, I'm facing the same problem. I've added `X-Requested-With` and/or `X-Prototype-Version`, but it didn't fix it. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late with an answer but i fixed this by adding an line in _urllib2_forked.py

on line 1098 stands the line: `headers["Connection"] = "Close"`

Change this to:

`if not 'Connection' in headers:
            headers["Connection"] = "Close"`

and make sure you set the header in you script and it will work.

Gr. Squandor