# Set Connection:Keep alive using mechanize in python

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying a send a HTTP header which should contain

```
Connection:keep-alive
```

but when i add headers using:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders[('Connection','keep-alive')'''and some other headers''']
```

and send the request and analyse the sent header using Fiddler4, i get the connection status:

```
Connection:'close'
```

how can i manage to keep the session alive

this is the header i am trying to send with python mechanize, which results in a

HTTPError: HTTP Error 408: Request Timed Out

```
POST http://site21.way2sms.com/smstoss.action HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://site21.way2sms.com
Content-Length: 94
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Accept:      text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Host: site21.way2sms.com
Referer: http://site21.way2sms.com/sendSMS?    Token=4A0CB0CC3FD1F0EE7985FFB44E04C6B7.w814
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cookie: _gat=1; JSESSIONID=A08~4A0CB0CC3FD1F0EE7985FFB44E04C6B7.w814;  _ga=GA1.2.1739915090.1432824367
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

ssaction=ss&Token=4A0CB0CC3FD1F0EE7985FFB44E04C6B7.w814&mobile=9765272851&message=6&msgLen=139
```

and this is the header sent by the browser which shows the expected results:

```
POST http://site21.way2sms.com/smstoss.action HTTP/1.1
Host: site21.way2sms.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 94
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://site21.way2sms.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://site21.way2sms.com/sendSMS?   Token=877AAB22C3F0B1C3D15F71C04C8AB85C.w804
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gat=1; JSESSIONID=A04~877AAB22C3F0B1C3D15F71C04C8AB85C.w804;   _ga=GA1.2.1739915090.1432824367

         ssaction=ss&Token=877AAB22C3F0B1C3D15F71C04C8AB85C.w804&mobile=9765272851&message=3&msgLen=139
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Mechanize Prevent Connection:Close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693836/python-mechanize-prevent-connectionclose)

Comment: @Drenmi the suggested link doesnt seem to solve the problem, i updated my post to give the actaual headers

Comment: Am working on the same stuff O_o Way2SMS O_o

Comment: @RachitKumarRihar, I'm facing the same problem here. Did you reach a solution? If so, please post it or give the link. Thanks :)

Comment: @RachitKumarRihar Is this fixed? i am facing the same problem. Could you please help